# ¿Posible restriccion en Eclipse? con Java

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Tengo en mi codigo varios System.out.println() preguntando determinadas cosas y recogiendo en su variable correspondiente lo que introduce por el teclado el usuario.
El caso es que tras varios System.out.println() , Eclipse es como si ignorara el ultimo y no te dejara introducir nada por teclado porque ha avanzado con el programa.
He revisado una y otra vez el codigo en busca de errores pero nada.
Puede que se trate de alguna limitacion de Eclipse? Que opinais?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

PD: el trozo de codigo esta dentro de main

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String DNI = null;


        while((DNI == null) || (DNI.equals("")) || DNI.length()<6){

            System.out.println("El DNI es obligatorio para la creacion "
                            + "de un alumno.");

            System.out.println("Introduce el DNI: ");
            DNI = sc.nextLine();

            if(DNI!=null && DNI.length()<6){
                System.out.println("El DNI introducido es demasiado corto.");
                    }
                }


        System.out.println("Introduce la direccion: ");
        String direccion = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
        String nombre = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento "
                + "(AAAA-MM-DD): ");
        String edad = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce el telefono: ");
        int telefono = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduce el cif de empresa: ");
        String CIFEmpresa = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

## Problema

El problema está en el `sc.nextInt()`.
Esta función solo leerá un entero, pero como has pulsado *Enter* para mandarlo, también has enviado un `\n` por lo que tu siguiente llamada a `nextLine()` leerá ese `\n`.

## Ejemplo del problema

Te pongo en situación. Supongamos que hago lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
nextLine();
System.out.println("Introduce la edad: ");
nextInt();
System.out.println("Introduce el apellido: ");
nextLine();
System.out.println("Fin.");
```

Para rellenar esos datos, yo mandaría los siguientes inputs (los `\n`no son visibles, pero te los pongo para que los veas):

```
Introduce el nombre: 
DanielGS\n
Introduce la edad:
23\n
Introduce el apellido:
Fin.
```

**¿Que ha pasado ahí?** Pues que el nextLine() para obtener el apellido ha cogido el `\n` de la edad, ya que nextInt() solo te coge el entero.

### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Simplemente añadiendo un nextLine() para que coja ese `\n` que se queda por ahí.

```
System.out.println("Introduce el nombre: ");
nextLine();
System.out.println("Introduce la edad: ");
nextInt();
nextLine();
System.out.println("Introduce el apellido: ");
nextLine();
System.out.println("Fin.");
```

> Otra opción podría ser leer la edad con un nextLine() y luego hacer una conversión a entero.